Help me find this tv series : weird unkillable evil neighbor
I've seen it long ago (prolly 10 years ish now?), only like once or twice, pretty sure it was a tv show and not a movie but could even be wrong on that, all i remember is:

There is a guy and a girl (not sure if his wife, think it is, could just be a date) living next door to some unkillable dude
I think the unkillable guy was a demon, he definately has a human form however.
The unkillable guy's purpose is messing with his neighbor's life. 
The "good" guy knows what the unkillable neighbor is, the girl doesn't and he acts as a normal neighbor next to her. 

I have no clue what this was nor am i even sure it was a tv show, no amount of Google fu is helping with the tons of recent demon / mystical / immortal shows that came up in recent years.

Could it be Fright Night? Or something inspired by this kind of thing (there is also a reboot, so you may look for the old version). The Neighboor is a vampire here.

All i could find googling fright night tv show was something about fighting contests. But no even going by your description it's not like that, even though he's immortal in the show (no clue why, could be a demon, could be something else) he looks perfectly human at all times visually (not a vampire, werewolf or anything like that, just a random neighbor to the unknowing, and only the next door guy seems to know about it and be harassed by him)

I'm talking about the movie. Since the plot seems similiar, it could be a good thing to search for related content.

Ok had a look at the trailer, definately not that. Also it didn't involve teenages at all, i'm talking well into adulthood people (don't remember precisely, but probably in the 30-40 age bracket) for both men Neighbors.

@RonanThibaudau Do you know what country it was from? How old was it when you watched it? Do you remember the characters' ethnicity? And was it a comedy or a drama?

And lastly, what made you think he was unkillable?

I remember 2 sequences (i "think" they were right after each other, but i'm not sure, i do am sure about both sequence's existence). 1) the evil dude tells the man (or the man understands from his act or whatever) that his wife will die, and he runs to save her and 2) the "good guy" kills the evil neighbor, except when he runs back to his wife, he's here with a big grin and completely unharmed.

All 3 characters i can remember were white (good guy, evil neighboor and good guy's wife). I'm fairly certain it was a US show (i saw it in france, but it "felt" like the other US shows in filming style). For the era i really don't know when i watched it but i'm sure about the apartment from which i watched it, which means i couldn't be younger than 12 so it was definately at least 1996. So all i know for sure about the date is i probably saw it somewhere between 1996 and 2005. Could be older as it could be re airing but not substantially older as it didn't "look old"

For comedy / drama i'd say neither but i really only remember a couple scenes and images, not sure why it's coming back up (haven't thought of it for years!). It definately wasn't a comedy, but i don't remember enough about it to classify it clearly, i know it wasn't any form of "haha" comedy from the scenes i remember, but it definately wasn't dramatic either. Also i'm not 100% sure it was a tv series (could be a movie) but somehow i remember it "as a serie", what makes me think i could be wrong is i can't remember more than 2 scènes, so maybe i saw a re run 2 times at diferent parts and

wrongly assumed it was a serie

Here's a possibility: The War Next Door (2000), a short-lived American live action show by the makers of The Adventures of Pete & Pete. From Wiki:

Kennedy Smith, a super secret agent, just wants to retire. Unfortunately, his seemingly indestructible nemesis, Kriegman, wants to make his life hell and so moves into the suburbs and becomes Smith's next-door neighbor and evil opponent.

IMDb describes the evil neighbor as immortal, and the characters kept dying but then came back to life in the next episode. Here's the cast:


YES YES YES!! 100% yes, i remember the evil dude's face on the left ! :)

That was fast, says i can't award the Bounty untill 22 more hours, won't forget!

Glad you found it. :) I don't think I saw this question before, so good thinking bumping it up.
